# How to detect a NaN in list directed input in fortran

Tags: input, fortran, nan, detect

I read real valued data from an input file with list directed input. What is the best way to detect a NaN via `iostat=iostatus`?

As an example for the input for a large program I need to read a file like:

```
1   NaN    1.0
2   nan    2.0
```

where there are occasionally "NaN"s instead of real valued numbers. 
with `READ(ird, *, iostat=iostatus) nr, r1, r2` 
no iostatus is flagged for gfortran 7.4.0 on UBUNTU!

Apparently the input error is treated as a quiet NaN instead of a signalling NaN. 
The gfortran compiler options do not seem to provide an option to turn this into a signalling NaN. 
The fortran standard at 
https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf
does not specify treatment of a Nan in list directed input.

In section 13.7.2.3.2 there is info for formatted input, and it specifically states that the Nan on input is treated as a quiet NaN.

I found a documentation on the NAG compiler and it states explicitely that a NaN on input is never flagged as a signalling NaN.

The philosophy behind these decisions in the standard beats me. I would have expected that this shoud be an error.

If the line is changed to:

```
read(ird, *, err=10, iostat=iostatus) nr, r1, r2
10 continue
```

the iostatus changes to +5001 ! But I do not really want to resort back to the ancient `err=` clause.

I am aware that I could read the line into a character string, analyze the string for the presence of any "NaN" and proceed. I could as in the example analyse `ieee_is_nan()`. That seems however unnecessarily tedious given the `iostat=` clause.

So is there a compiler option that I missed ?

```
PROGRAM main
USE ieee_arithmetic
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: IRD = 12
INTEGER :: iostatus
REAL    :: r1 = -1.0, r2 = -1.0
INTEGER :: nr = 0
CHARACTER(LEN=1024) :: line = ' '

OPEN(UNIT=IRD,FILE='data.data', STATUS='old')

READ(IRD, *, IOSTAT=iostatus, IOMSG=line) nr, r1, r2
WRITE(*,*) iostatus, nr, r1, r2, ieee_is_nan(r1), line(1:LEN_TRIM(line))

r1 = -1.0
r2 = -1.0

READ(IRD, ERR=10, IOSTAT=iostatus, IOMSG=line) nr, r1, r2
10 CONTINUE
WRITE(*,*) iostatus, nr, r1, r2, ieee_is_nan(r1), line(1:LEN_TRIM(line))

CLOSE(UNIT=IRD)
END PROGRAM main
```

The output of my program is:  (Shortened insignificant digits and blanks)

```
0  1              NaN   1.00 T 
5001  1  -1.00      -1.00 F
Missing format for FORMATTED data transfer
```

At the first read iostatus is set to 0, while on the second read its set to 5001!

Comment: Have you considered using the `IEEE_ARITHMETIC` module?  You read the data, and then use the `IEEE_IS_NAN` intrinsic subprogram to check each value for an NaN.

Comment: Yes, in my actual program I have corrected the situation with something like: if(iostatus/=0  .OR. ieee_is_nan(r1) then ... This would however be a maintanence nightmare as the code is som 150000 lines of code with numerous different input sections.

Comment: if you don't want the qNaN to propagate you have two choices: either check for the NaN with `ieee_is_nan` or (with gfortran) use the -ffpe-trap=invalid option.

Comment: Thanks to francescalus for the edit, makes my question more readable!

Comment: Steve, I did try the -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,denormal option. The program still persists without an error message, even if I add a line r2=r1+r2 after the first read/write with r1 in the NaN status. . Gfortran seems to be rather resilient to reals with NaN status.  My current conclusion is that I'll have to add either the err= claus and an emtpy 'continue' line immediatly after the faulty read or resort to the combined test for iostatus and ieee_is_nan. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You are getting the error because you have omitted a format in your `read`.  I would need to go root through the standard, but I vaguely recall that if an error occurs during a read then all variables are technically undefined.  I am surprised that adding `r2=r1+r2` did not raise an exception.  I know some fixes for IEEE_ARITHMETIC were added recently to newer versions of gfortran.  In some cases the fenv exception mask wasn't cleared properly.